# my interpreter is showing syntax error for the code given below . can you help debug it?

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
n=int(input())
ls=[]
ls=list(map(int,input().split())
b=0
```

Here the interpreter is showing a syntax error. How do I tackle this?

```
c=0
mx=ls[0]
mn=ls[0]
for i in range(1,n):
    if ls[i]>mx:
    b+=1
    mx=ls[i]
    if ls[i]<mn:
        c+=1
        mn=ls[i]
print(b,c)
```

Comment: What's the error trace?

Comment: Check the number of opening and closing parentheses on the previous line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `)` at the end of line 3